# TypeError : list indices must be integers not str

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I'd like to create an alarm whose metric (trigger) is ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible in a Queue 'myDownlinQueue', the alarm takes the action of autoscaling an AutoScalingGroup. However based on the code I am writing I get the error mentioned in the title. Maybe I am doing it wrong, but below is the code that causes this error.

```
# ==== AutoSCaling config =======================
autoscaling_group = {
"name": "myAG", #descriptive name for your auto scaling group
"min_size": 0 , #Minimum number of instances that should be running at all times
"max_size": 0   #Maximum number of instances that should be running at all times
}


lc_name = 'myLG' #Descriptive name for your launch configuration

#=================AMI to launch======================================================
as_ami = {
"id": "ami-******c", #The AMI ID of the instance your Auto Scaling group will launch
"VpcId" : "vpc-0c805575",
"security_groups": "sg-xxxxxxxa", #The security group(s) your instances will belong to
"instance_type": "t2.micro", #The size of instance that will be launched
"instance_monitoring": True #Indicated whether the instances will be launched with detailed monitoring enabled. Needed to enable CloudWatch
}


conn_reg = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region_name=awsRegion)
zones = conn_reg.get_all_zones()

zoneStrings = []
for zone in zones:
    zoneStrings.append(zone.name)
    print " Available zones : " + zone.name

conn_vpc = boto.connect_vpc()
subnetids = conn_vpc.get_all_subnets()


conn_as = AutoScaleConnection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_SECRET_KEY)

lc = LaunchConfiguration(name = lc_name, 
                         image_id = as_ami["id"],
                         instance_type = as_ami["instance_type"],
                         user_data = "user-data.bls",
                         associate_public_ip_address = True,
                         instance_monitoring=as_ami["instance_monitoring"])

conn_as.create_launch_configuration(lc)

ag = AutoScalingGroup(group_name = autoscaling_group["name"], 
                      availability_zones= zoneStrings,
                      vpc_zone_identifier = subnetList,
                      launch_config=lc, min_size = autoscaling_group["min_size"], 
                      max_size = autoscaling_group["max_size"])
conn_as.create_auto_scaling_group(ag)


#=================Create Scaling Policies===================================
# Policy for scaling the number of servers up and down

scalingUpPolicy = ScalingPolicy(name = "myScaleUpPolicy",
                                          adjustment_type ="ChangeInCapacity",
                                          as_name=ag.name,
                                          scaling_adjustment = numInstances ,
                                          cooldown=180)

scalingDownPolicy = ScalingPolicy(name = "myScaleDownPolicy",
                                           adjustment_type= "ExactCapacity",
                                           as_name=ag.name,
                                           scaling_adjustment= 0 ,
                                           cooldown=180)

conn_as.create_scaling_policy(scalingUpPolicy)
conn_as.create_scaling_policy(scalingDownPolicy)


scalingUpPolicy = conn_as.get_all_policies(as_group="myAG", policy_names=["myScaleUpPolicy"])[0]
scalingDownPolicy = conn_as.get_all_policies(as_group="myAG",policy_names=["myScaleDownPolicy"])[0]


# =========== CloudWatch Connection =============
cw = connect_to_region(awsRegion)    

# ===========  SNS Connection ===================
sns = connect_to_region(awsRegion)

cw = CloudWatchConnection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_SECRET_KEY)
sqs = SQSConnection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_SECRET_KEY)



# ==== Alarm =================
numberOfMessages = 1
metric_object = cw.list_metrics(dimensions={"QueueName":"myDownlinkQueue"}, metric_name = "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible",namespace = "AWS/SQS")

alarm_name = "myAlarm"

metric_object["ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible"].create_alarm(name =alarm_name, 
                                             comparison=">=", 
                                             threshold = numberOfMessages, 
                                             period = 60, 
                                             evaluation_periods = 1, 
                                             statistic = "Average", 
                                             alarm_actions=[scalingDownPolicy.policy_arn])
```

The error is in the last method - creating an alarm, precisely scalingDownPolicy.policy_arn

Comment: The question contais way too many lines of code and lack the whole error message (the traceback contains line numbers and can indicate if the problems happens in your code or inside other library).

Comment: @PauloScardine  The error is in the title and it happens in the last line, if I comment the last line I don't get the error. The problem is precisely scalingDownPolicy.policy_arn. create_alarm method expects a list of indices to arn not the string, but I was using an example from  http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/autoscale_tut.html   , How do I create an alarm that uses SQS metric with actions on autoscaling ?

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit: `scalingDownPolicy.policy_arn` is a string, but you need an integer for the function call. What is your confusion?

Comment: @MarkRansom  Following the example in the docs gives this error. How does one get the indices for the policy_arn ?

Comment: What is the value of the string? Does `scalingDownPolicy.policy_arn.isdigit()` returns `True`? if so, you can pass it as `int(scalingDownPolicy.policy_arn)`. The traceback is still useful if you want someone to debug code for you because we can look at the source of the module where the problem happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either OP misread the documentation or confuse.

According to boto2   [cloudwatch.list_metric()](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/cloudwatch.html), the item will return a `list`.

> list_metrics(next_token=None, dimensions=None, metric_name=None,
>   namespace=None)
>
> Returns a list of the valid metrics for which there is recorded data
>   available.

So `metric_object["ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible"]` will kick error `TypeError : list indices must be integers not str`

OTH, boto3 cloudwatch.list_object return a dict. And they are NOT compatible. However, none of the dictionary key having ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible.

```
{
    'Metrics': [
        {
            'Namespace': 'string',
            'MetricName': 'string',
            'Dimensions': [
                {
                    'Name': 'string',
                    'Value': 'string'
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
    'NextToken': 'string'
}
```